# Elastic search configurations not working in laravel v5.3

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have setup new laravel v5.3 project and install elastic search driver to implement elastic search via composer. But when I reload my page then I always receive This page isn’t working even the elastic search is running on my system below is my complete code that I code.

composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^6.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
    },
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/',array('uses' => 'ElasticSearch@addPeopleList'));
```

Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;    
class ElasticSearch extends Controller
    {

        // elastic
        protected $elastic;
        //elastic cliend
        protected $client;

        public function __construct(Client $client)
        {
            $this->client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
            $config = [
                'host' =>'localhost',
                'port' =>9200,
                'index' =>'people',
            ];
            $this->elastic = new ElasticClient($config);
        }

        public function addPeopleList(){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($this->$elastic);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

But when I refresh the page then This page isn’t working i received this message and page not loaded one thing that I want to let you know that I made no changes in app.php file of configuration. Please eduacate to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

if You want to instantiate an elastic client with some configuration, You should use method `ClientBuilder::fromConfig(array $config)`.
In your case it should be

```
<?php
$client = ClientBuilder::fromConfig([
    'hosts' => [ 'localhost:9200' ]
]);
```

As You can notice above hosts must be provided as array.

Also I'm not sure that Elasticsearch client that You use have `ElasticClient` class.

Also if You provided actual code from your controller than it contains an error. You should call class properties like that: `print_r($this->client)` (without `$` near the property name).

Finaly your controller should looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

class ElasticSearch extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var \Elasticsearch\Client
     */
    protected $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = ClientBuilder::fromConfig([
            'hosts' => [
                'localhost:9200',
            ],
        ]);
    }
    public function addPeopleList(){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->client);
        exit;
    }
}
```

And to add a document to the index You need to call this command according to the official documentation

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id',
    'body' => ['testField' => 'abc']
];

$response = $client->index($params);
print_r($response);
```

Official documentation can be found here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php

P.S. Sorry for my English. It is far from perfect.